# How do I prevent the triangle of doom when accessing JSON Data?

Tags: ios, swift

I am traversing some JSON Data where I need to access nested elements. Currently the easiest way is manually traverse the JSON Data as dictionaries like so

```
typealias JSON = AnyObject
typealias JSONDictionary = Dictionary<String, JSON>
typealias JSONArray = Array<JSON>

if let jsonData = data["preview"] as? JSONDictionary {
    if let source: JSON = jsonData["images"] as? JSONArray {
        if let images = source[0] as? JSONDictionary {
            if let image = images["source"] as? JSONDictionary {
                if let url = image["url"] as? String {
                    self.imageURL = url
                    getPhoto()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems unsustainable and the code is ugly. 
Is there a better way to do this? How can I better traverse JSON data?

Comment: SwiftyJSON is explaining exactly this and is a library to work around https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: @Christian excellent thank you, if you want to post up the answer I'll mark it as answered

Comment: In Swift 1.2, this has been addressed—but still somewhat ugly. See [Swift 1.2 - Is SwiftyJSON still usefull](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/175)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this using multiple levels seperated by commas:

```
if let
    jsonData = data["preview"] as? JSONDictionary,
    source   = jsonData["images"] as? JSONArray,
    images   = source[0] as? JSONDictionary,
    image    = images["source"] as? JSONDictionary,
    url      = image["url"] as? String
{
    self.imageURL = url
    getPhoto()
}
```